# What is the component argument type passing in ReactDOM.render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-eslint

I am trying to write a function to help test each components.

```
function testComponent(component: any): void {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(component, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
}
```

I got a warning from [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) when run lint.

> warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type 
>   @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

So I try to see what passes in `ReactDOM.render`, here it is

```
export interface Renderer {
    // Deprecated(render): The return value is deprecated.
    // In future releases the render function's return type will be void.

    <T extends Element>(
        element: DOMElement<DOMAttributes<T>, T>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): T;

    (
        element: Array<DOMElement<DOMAttributes<any>, any>>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): Element;

    (
        element: SFCElement<any> | Array<SFCElement<any>>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): void;

    <P, T extends Component<P, ComponentState>>(
        element: CElement<P, T>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): T;

    (
        element: Array<CElement<any, Component<any, ComponentState>>>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): Component<any, ComponentState>;

    <P>(
        element: ReactElement<P>,
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): Component<P, ComponentState> | Element | void;

    (
        element: ReactElement[],
        container: Element | null,
        callback?: () => void
    ): Component<any, ComponentState> | Element | void;
}
```

The typing is a little big, and I cannot find a type which can replace `any` directly.

I tried `Component`, but it gives this warning on my IDE

> Argument of type 'Component<{}, {}, any>' is not assginable to
>   parameter of type 'TreactElement
>   ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)>[]'.

Is there a such a type or other ways to fix it without ignoring the lint warning? Thanks

Comment: use ReactElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed `ReactElement`.

I originally thought it should be the type `Component` because I passed in a component. Turns out it is `ReactElement`.

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

function testComponent(component: ReactElement): void {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(component, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
}
```

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly oh because I don’t understand based on the typing files, there are many kind of types for elements, but why ReactElement is enough to pass the lint.

Comment: I got it, it is simply because I am using one kind of type ReactElement, that is why it works. Don’t know what I was thinking before..